# Nodemon execute different scripts based on the changed file name

Tags: nodemon

I am trying to make Nodemon run two different commands depending on which file changed. I tried using `nodemon.json` and invoking it using `nodemon nodemon.json` (because it didn't seem to be getting picked up just by `nodemon`):

```
{
  "watch": "nodemon.json,main.js,index.js",
  "execMap": {
    "main.js": "electron .",
    "index.js": "echo todo",
    "nodemon.json": "echo Nodemon config reloaded"
  }
}
```

Nodemon doesn't pick up any changes with this setup. I think I might have a problem in the `watch` glob. When I remove it (so it watches everything I think by default), then file changes are getting picked up, but Nodemon only ever executes `node index.js`. I never speficied that anywhere so I assume that's the default and the `execMap` is not being honored? Is it only for extensions?

I am not sure how to craft a config which takes these two different paths. Is it even possible with Nodemon?

Answer (score 0):

The `execMap` property seems to be intended to support non-default file extensions.

According to [the docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#default-executables)

> ...you can define your own default executables using the execMap
> property. This is particularly useful if you're working with a
> language that isn't supported by default by nodemon

One thing you can do is run multiple nodemon processes, one for each file/directory, from a script, like:

```
nodemon -w "path1/" -x "<command 1>" &
nodemon -w "path2/" -x "<command 2>"
```